# Feature with an listinstance and eventreceiver to modify version settings, order issue?

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, feature-receiver

I created in vs an listinstance. I add this list instance to a feature. In this feature I created a feature event receiver to modify the version settings. I see now when the feature event receiver is fired, the list instance is not existed yet. So this is an order issue. How can I fix this?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

            if(web == null)
            {
                throw new SPException("Invalid feature scope");
            }

            // set library versioning
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("DMSDocumenten");
            if (list != null)
            {
                list.EnableVersioning = true;
                list.EnableMinorVersions = true;
                list.MajorVersionLimit = ConfigBeheerIntranet.Current.Major_VersionLimit;
                list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = ConfigBeheerIntranet.Current.MajorWithMinor_VersionsLimit;
                list.ForceCheckout = true;
                list.DraftVersionVisibility = DraftVisibilityType.Author;
                list.Update();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using ListAdded event reciever instead ?

Comment: I do not want to use ListAdded event receiver because it is only for 1 library.

Comment: Use two features : 1. Provisions list instance 2. Used to configure list created by feature 1 - add dependecy on Feature 1 being activated before. Feature 2 can also be hidden and activated using powershell. other option to consider would using JSOM or CSOM for configuring list instance. Beauty of using JSOM is that you can just run the code using your browser console.